# jQuery, get ID of each element in a class using .each?

Tags: jquery, element, each

I'm trying this to get the `id` of each element in a `class` but instead it's alerting each name of the class separately, so for `class="test"` it's alerting: `t`, `e`, `s`, `t`... Any advice on how to get the each element `id` that is part of the `class` is appreciated, as I can't seem to figure this out.. Thanks.

```
$.each('test', function() { 
   alert(this)
});
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Try this, replacing `.myClassName` with the actual name of the class (but keep the period at the beginning).

```
$('.myClassName').each(function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

So if the class is "test", you'd do `$('.test').each(func...`.

This is the specific form of `.each()` that iterates over a jQuery object.

The form you were using iterates over *any* type of collection. So you were essentially iterating over an array of characters `t,e,s,t`.

Using *that* form of `$.each()`, you would need to do it like this:

```
$.each($('.myClassName'), function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

...which will have the same result as the example above.

Comment: thanks, your answer is instructive!

Answer (score 30):

**patrick dw**'s answer is right on.

For kicks and giggles I thought I would post a simple way to return an array of all the IDs.

```
var arrayOfIds = $.map($(".myClassName"), function(n, i){
  return n.id;
});
alert(arrayOfIds);
```

Comment: Indeed `$.map()` is very nice if an Array is desired. Although if I may express my personal bias, I'd do `n.id` instead of creating a new jQuery object for each iteration since it's a good deal more efficient. Just thought I'd mention it. :o)

Comment: you're right patrick. no need for the extra $(). I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
        });
    });
```