# How to get the ids of all elements of a particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have following code and want to get the id of all elements that belong to particular class.

**`code`**

```
<ul>
<li><label class="check-lbl"><input id="1" class="translation_box" type="checkbox">اردو</label</li>
    <li><label class="check-lbl"><input id="3" class="translation_box" type="checkbox">Englisg</label> </li>
    <li><label class="check-lbl"><input id="4" class="translation_box" type="checkbox">Hindi</label> </li>
    <li><label class="check-lbl"><input id="5" class="translation_box" type ="checkbox">Bungali</label> </li>
  < /ul>
```

here i am talking `translation_box`. any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do note that ID names are not allowed to start with a number.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes In HTML5, IDs can start with a number - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery, get ID of each element in a class using .each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485825/jquery-get-id-of-each-element-in-a-class-using-each)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery

```
$('.translation_box').each( function () {
 alert($(this).prop('id'));

});
```

---

Using JS

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('translation_box');
for (var i=0; i< ele.length; i++ ) {
  alert(ele[i].id);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/LG59D/1/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** to directly get the list of IDs from a jquery collection.

```
var ids = $('.translation_box').map(function(_, x) { return x.id; }).get();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZNxP7/1/

Comment: You forget to add the `.get();` at the end. Basic `.map()` return an jQuery object instead of an Array. See http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 2):

```
var allItemsInClass = $(".translation_box");
var arrayIDs = new Array();
$.each(allItemsInClass, function() {
   arrayIDs.push(this.id);
});
alert(arrayIDs.join());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LG59D/

Comment: You could just use `$(".translation_box").each(...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to do so.

```
$(function(){
  var elements = new Array();
  $('.translation_box').each(function(){
    elements.push($(this).attr("id"))
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.translation_box').each(function() {   // this loops through all elements with class of tranlation_box
     var x = $(this).attr('id');          // this gets the id of each translation_box and stores it in the variable x
     console.log(x);                      // this logs the id for each one
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the following:

```
 function getIds() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("translation_box");

   for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].getAttribute("id"));
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It returns all id's in an Array

```
var idArray = [];

$('.translation_box').each(function() {
               var id = $(this).attr('id');
               idArray.push(id);
            });
alert(idArray)
```