# How to increment the value for an element locator using javascript

Tags: javascript, element, playwright

I need to grab the element for "n" of rows however the element value increments as below:

```
<select aria-invalid="false" id="select-fieldName-0-1" class="css-14xtrl2">. 
<select aria-invalid="false" id="select-fieldName-0-1-0" class="css-14xtrl2">.
<select aria-invalid="false" id="select-fieldName-0-1-1-0" class="css-14xtrl2">.
<select aria-invalid="false" id="select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-0" class="css-14xtrl2">.
```

and so on.
How can I grab the element "id" to loop it for "n" number of times?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You forgot sharing how it is incremented. Please share that info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through ID elements in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299495/how-to-loop-through-id-elements-in-html)

Comment: have you been able to solve the incrementation in the meantime @bhaws?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you're incrementing like that, but if i understand correctly you want to pick the value of all of them. Following @happyvirus comment you should do this:

`const selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=select-fieldName]');`

The `^` means a "starts like".

Then you could just loop selectBoxes, pick values, manipulate them, whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Jon . Basically I am testing for a feature where we need to keep adding a condition upto 15times. And it need to click on the previous id, ex: `id="select-fieldName-0-1"` which then generates `id="select-fieldName-0-1-0"` and I need to click on the new generated ID to add the next condition which then generates 'id="select-fieldName-0-1-1-0" and click on that and so on until I reach the 15th position :(. Even I failed to understand the incrementation this way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a consistent pattern in the transformation of the first three elements of your example. If I consider it accurate from the 2nd element then you are able to generate the selectors with the following JavaScript methods: [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

You can grab a string pattern (`'-0-1-'`) which after you will insert the incrementer string part (`'1-'`). *Note:* `Array.splice()` is an in-place array method, it is applied directly on the original array.

**Example (iterated 8 times):**

```js
let sel ='select-fieldName-0-1-0'
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  const selArr = sel.split('')
  selArr.splice(sel.indexOf('-0-1-') + '-0-1-'.length, 0, '1-')
  sel = selArr.join('')
  console.log(sel)
}
```

Output:

```
select-fieldName-0-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0
select-fieldName-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0
```

So if you are inside your main playwright script, then you can use the `for` loop to interact with the elements with the above selector pattern:

```js
for (...)
  ...
  await page.click(sel)
}
```

Place the playwright actions to the right place, e.g. the 1st iteration should be clicked before the for loop starts if follow my example.